# Checkboxes vs. Checkboces

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I know that you can say both e.g. indexes and indices, but does it apply to all the words with similar ending?

I'm interested about checkboxes vs checkboces in particular.

Comment: *Checkboces* is **not** a word, at least not in the sense of the plural of *checkbox*. QED.

Comment: Hello, Athelhard, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Have you done any research into the status of _checkboces_ on your own? If so, what did you find?

Comment: Hello Sven, it's Ath*a*lhard, but never mind :) Don't know what kind of 'research' are you talking about, but googling revealed that _checkboces_ is sometimes used as a plural of checkbox.

Comment: Also a duplicate of 'How do you decline nouns borrowed from languages with several categories for declining nouns (or none at all)?'

Comment: I apologize for misspelling of your name, Athalhard. I ran Google Books searches for _checkboces_ and _check boces_, and found zero instances of either, which suggests to me that occurrences of either term in edited publications is very rare indeed. That's why I was curious about where you had run into the spelling _checkboces_. Perhaps you could add a link in your question to a (relatively reputable-looking) example from Google's all-Web search?

Comment: @SvenYargs I must say, I wasn't not interested if it's used in any publications, I was interested whether 'checkboces' is grammatically correct at all. To understand that I needed to know, is it different from, say, "index", and if it is - how exactly. Some_Guy provided me that information.

I don't accept _ad hominem_ arguments, sorry.

Comment: The conditions of being *(a)* “grammatically correct at all” and *(b)* “used in any publications” are far more closely linked than you may suppose, Athalhard. Apart from actual usage (and especially usage that editors pass), just what do you suppose “grammatically correct at all” even means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it only applies to words with a latin root where the plural is imported from latin too?  There's no general plural rule for "*x" words, just a few that follow an exception to the expected "*xes".

Some other exception I can think of are

axis -> axes (pronounced "akzeez")

matrix -> matrices (maitrisseez)

there's no :

boxes -> boces

foxes -> foces

<s>dominatrix -> dominatrices.</s>     As pointed out by Brian Donovan, this is actually an acceptable variant.

It's just like mouse and mice, no rule, just memorisation.

Comment: English, easy as it is, would be _much_ easier without all those "no rule" rules :) Thanks.

Comment: no problem :)  further info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Irregular_plurals_from_Latin_and_Greek

Comment: Although its' a bit archaic, its worth noting that certain words are pluralized with the -en suffix too. Consider Oxen for instance.

Comment: Think again on *dominatrices* as plural of *dominatrix:* see [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dominatrix) and [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dominatrixes%2C+dominatrices&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) on the subject

Comment: Please use "comments" to post your opinions, not "answer."

Comment: which comment do you have a problem with here?  Each person seems to be adding a helpful correction or refinement to my answer